# jquery cookies when loaded are not replace old values. Instead they are being place to the side infinitely

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Alright, first thing to note is this is my second day working with javascript, and my first time trying to implement cookies. That being said whenever it does manage to load the cookies it does not replace the values of the cookies. Instead it places the value next to the old one, ex. if the value is 1, and the cookie have .47 saved, it will become 1.47, and eventually it will expand as the script reruns it numbers like this pop up (0.60000000000000012.524.924924902490024900024900002490000024900000024...) I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here is my code.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<title>Power Plant </title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/looksyo.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/main.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery-migrate.js"></script>

<h1> Plant Power </h1>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> getCookies() </script>
<table>
<!-- First Column, this will be where I keep the Tender shiz -->
<td class=leftColumn>
Tender:
<span id="tender">0</span><br/> </br>
You gain tender based on a kilowatt second.
</td>
<!-- Second columns The BUTTON! Please wait while the button calibrates. -->

<td class=centerColumn>
<div class="buttonStyle">
<br /> </br>
Watt Button
<br /> </br>
<input type="submit" value="SaveTest" onClick=setCookies()></input>
<button type="submit" hidefocus=true onClick=wattClick(1)><span id="watts">0</span></button>
</div>
</td>
<!-- Third columns buildings -->
<td class=rightColumn>
<div id="crankStyle" >
<button type="submit" onClick=purchaseCrank()> Buy Cranks </button>
<span id="cranks">0</span> <br /> </br>
Crank Cost:<span id="crankCost">10</span>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

And the js

```
//resources
var watts = 0;
var tender = 0;
//buildings
var cranks = 0;

//Gaining Watts from the watt button

function wattClick(number) {
watts = watts + number;
document.getElementById("watts").innerHTML = watts;
}

function purchaseCrank() {
var crankCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cranks));
if(tender > crankCost - 1) {
cranks = cranks + 1;
tender = tender - crankCost;
document.getElementById("cranks").innerHTML = cranks;
document.getElementById("tender").innerHTML = tender; };
var nextCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.1,cranks));
document.getElementById("crankCost").innerHTML = nextCost;
};



//Building Passives
window.setInterval(function(){
wattClick(cranks);
}, 1000);








//For debugging
function tenderClick(number){
tender = tender + number;
document.getElementById("tender").innerHTML = tender;
};


//Ways to Gain Tender
window.setInterval(function(){
tenderClick(Math.round(10*watts/1000)/10);
}, 1000);


//Figuring out how to write cookies, yay.
//escaping the values before writing them
//var eWatts = escape(watts);
//var eTender = escape(tender);
//var eCranks = escape(cranks);

//This should write the needed cookies
function setCookies(){
$.cookie("watts", escape(watts), {expires: 10000});
$.cookie("tender", escape(tender), {expires: 10000});
$.cookie("cranks", escape(cranks), {expires: 10000});
}

function getCookies(){
check1 = $.cookie("watts");
check2 = $.cookie("tender");
check3 = $.cookie("cranks");
if (check1 == null || check2 == null || check3 == null) {
setCookies()
}
else
{
watts = unescape($.cookie("watts"));
tender = unescape($.cookie("tender"));
cranks = unescape($.cookie("cranks"));
document.getElementById("watts").innerHTML = watts;
document.getElementById("tender").innerHTML = tender;
document.getElementById("cranks").innerHTML = cranks;
};
};
```

I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong when it comes to calling the cookies and putting them into place. I have read and tried implementing several methods and the problem either persist, or it won't have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the symptom you described, it must has nothing to do with cookies.

It is obvious when you are doing the math, you are using string instead of numbers.

Javascript does not do automatic type conversion, also, it use '+' for both string concatenation and numeric addition.

Thus lines like:

```
cranks = cranks + 1;
```

Should be

```
cranks = parseFloat(cranks) + 1;
```

Comment: You're correct, I was too busy focussing on the cookies that I didn't think to parse the cookie values once they were read.

'watts = parseFloat($.cookie("watts"));' 

Fixed the issue.